# How to include multiple conditions in an if function in PHP?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have been trying to put multiple conditions in PHP in an if function. I tried the following, but it is not working:

```
if ($extension == "png" || == "jpg" || == "gif") {
    echo "<img src='images/".$name."' width='10%' >";
}
```

How can I add multiple conditions to this if function?

Comment: I know I can use Switch loop in php but I want to know if it is possible in If function please..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to repeat the entire condition again..

```
if ($extension == "png" || $extension == "jpg" || $extension == "gif")
```

Here's another way to achieve the same thing

```
if (in_array($extension, array('jpg', 'png', 'gif')))
```

Personally I use the second method as I find it much easier to come back to later and add more conditions to.

Comment: Yup..! Thanks what I wanted to know was the second method in_array and thanks for that...!

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($extension == "png" || $extension == "jpg" || $extension == "gif") {
echo "<img src='images/".$name."' width='10%' >";
}
```

Comment: Thanks..!But I already knew it to repeat again and again the full condition with just different parameters but I wanted to know if there is an easy way to do that without repeating the whole condition every time..!

Comment: as suggested by Dale use in_array function